# Menu button long press action

Tags: android, button, menu, long-press

When I press menu button long, phone is vibrating. How to connect long press of menu key to some action. For example, to changeMyLang() method. Is it possible to do like that?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10530517/override-menu-key-long-press-and-launch-an-application-on-long-press

Answer (score 1):

By default, `ActionBar` items show the `title` attribute in a tooltip. You cannot override this functionality. You can, however, create a custom `ActionProvider`, where you can set a `View.OnLongClickListener` on *it*.

Check out the "ApiDemo" `ActionBarSettingsActionProviderActivity`. ([link](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.3_r1/com/example/android/apis/app/ActionBarSettingsActionProviderActivity.java)) Using that as a starting point, the `onCreateActionView` of your `ActionProvider` would look something like this:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateActionView() {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.action_bar_custom_action_provider, null);

        ImageButton button = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Respond to normal click
            }
        });
        button.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                // Respond to long-click
                return true;
            }
        }
        return view;
    }
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you're talking about overriding the hardware menu button, you can do that, but only while in your app. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4681762/377260) for snippets on how to hook into the key event.

Comment: Just reread your question and realized you might be talking about the system menu button ("hardware" button). If so, this answer has nothing to do with that. I thought you meant `Menu` button.